# "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array" error message

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on an Activation Queue for new accounts on my website.

The system will work by iterating through an array with each new user account details in and then display them so the Admin can either accept or deny the account. To collect the account details and display them in an array I'm using the following piece of code, however I get the error "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given". I have no clue why this is being caused and I have tried various things previously suggested. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();

require "classes.php";
$TF = new TF_Core ();

$ActQueueQuery = "SELECT username, surname, forename, joined FROM users
WHERE rank = 'Unactivated'";

if ($statement = TF_Core::$MySQLi->DB->prepare($ActQueueQuery)) {
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->get_result();
}

if($results->num_rows == 0){
    $data = 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION["ActQueue"] = "";

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        $_SESSION["ActQueue"] = array_push($_SESSION["ActQueue"], array($row["username"], $row["surname"], $row["forname"], $row["joined"]));
    }
    $data = 0;
    }

echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION["ActQueue"] = "";` isn't defining an array, it's defining an empty string.... so how do you expect to push values to it as though it was an array?

Comment: you should start taking a look at your error messages and actually read them before asking online

Comment: $_SESSION["ActQueue"] = array(); or $_SESSION["ActQueue"] = array(""); Doing this still doesn't fix the error and besides the other array defines in the parameters of array_push() should have done the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["ActQueue"] = array(); // define an empty array

require "classes.php";
$TF = new TF_Core ();

$ActQueueQuery = "SELECT username, surname, forename, joined FROM users
WHERE rank = 'Unactivated'";

if ($statement = TF_Core::$MySQLi->DB->prepare($ActQueueQuery)) {
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->get_result();
}
if($results->num_rows == 0){
    $data = 1;
}
else{
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        $_SESSION["ActQueue"][] = array($row["username"], $row["surname"], $row["forname"], $row["joined"]); // check the change
    }
        $data = 0;
}
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: It throws no error, so I believe it probably worked. However, I think there is an issue elsewhere in another piece of code that prevents the results from being displayed. Hopefully when that's fixed either your suggestion or what I found from Musa will work. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth  which result you are talking about?

Comment: then do `echo json_encode($_SESSION["ActQueue"]);` and in your javascript code decode this json and loop over it and display all the result. If that will you want to do ten no need of session

Comment: It would be easier with future needs in mind to keep it in PHP code, so it wouldn't be an ideal solution I think. Plus, would it be hard to handle arrarys in arrays with json?

Comment: read how to decode json data into javascript array and loop through a javascript array

Comment: Yeh, actually I editted my post but ignore that. I can think of a way to do it suitably as you suggested. I'll read up on it now, though thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

"You are overwriting $arr_foundits on $arr_foundits = array_push($arr_foundits, $it->ID);. Remove the $arr_foundits = as array_push does not return the array but an int." Musa